# Why are npm commands spitting out all this console logging?

Tags: node.js, npm

Not finding anything on this from Google. Just updated npm to v7.20.3, and now with every command I'm getting a whole bunch of `npm timing config:load` and `npm timing npm:load` lines, even with a simple version check, and the command output at the very end:

[image: terminal screenshot showing lots of console log lines]

Is there some setting that just got set to "verbose" or something, that I can turn off, or am I stuck with all these lines of info that are the same every time and that I don't care about?

Comment: What is your [`npm config loglevel`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#loglevel) set to?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know what the setting was called to google it. Mine was set to info. I just reset it to the default of 'notice.'